# Colon in SQL Datatype?

Tags: types, syntax, sql-server-2005, user-defined-types

I've inherited a SQL Server 2005 database that has some data type syntax I've never seen before.  In the Design view for a table, the following columns are defined:

```
Column Name: "CustomerId"
Data Type: "pCustID:varchar(10)"

Column Name: "InvoiceNumber"
Data Type: "pInvoiceNum:varchar(15)"
```

Does anyone know what this datatype syntax represents?  Are the characters to the left of the data type purely a label? Does it define some sort of referential integrity measure or constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pCustID and pInvoiceNum are user defined data types.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[pCustID] FROM [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL
```

You can the use that as datatypes for columns in tables

```
create table YourTable
(
  ID pCustID
)
```

In MSSMS you find the user defined data types under `Programmability - User-Defined Data Types`.

When you design a table in MSSMS pCustID is presented with a `:` between the name of the user defined data type and the base data type.

[image]